# Integer value resetting to zero after function call (Playfab-Unity)

Tags: c#, azure, unity-game-engine

I need to get the highest score from the Playfab leaderboard list and show it in the Unity. I can get the highest score and then assign it to a global variable. My function returns this variable, but it is always returned as zero. The highest score value that is in the leaderboard is 50.

```
// GETS THE QUIZ'S, THAT THE USER HAS CLICKED, HIGHEST SCORE VALUE FROM THE PLAYFAB LEADERBOARD.
    public int GetLeaderboardList()
    {
        var request = new GetLeaderboardRequest();
        request.StartPosition = 0;
        request.StatisticName = QuizButtonClicked.clickedButtonQuiz.name; // the button that the user has clicked.
        request.MaxResultsCount = 20;
        PlayFabClientAPI.GetLeaderboard(request, (result) =>
        {
            topScoreOnLeaderboard = result.Leaderboard.ElementAt(0).StatValue;
            Debug.LogError(result.Leaderboard.ElementAt(0).StatValue); // 1- Result is 50.
            Debug.LogError(topScoreOnLeaderboard); // 2- Result is 50.

        }, (error) =>
        {
            Debug.LogError(error.GenerateErrorReport());
        });
        Debug.LogError(topScoreOnLeaderboard); // 3- But here it gives 0.
        return topScoreOnLeaderboard;
    }
```

Edit : Debug log order is 3-1-2.

Comment: `PlayFabClientAPI.GetLeaderboard()` will wait for a response before continuing execution right?

Comment: @Jake Yes, it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Debug log order is 3-1-2.`

This sounds like the `PlayFabClientAPI.GetLeaderboard()` is executed async or in a background thread.

the lines

```
Debug.LogError(topScoreOnLeaderboard); // 3- But here it gives 0.
return topScoreOnLeaderboard;
```

are simply reached before the result did actually arrive.

---

You have to wait until the result has arrived in order to continue.

I would use it e.g. via an `Action<int>` like

```
public void GetLeaderboardListAsync(Action<int> onResult)
{
    var request = new GetLeaderboardRequest();
    request.StartPosition = 0;
    request.StatisticName = QuizButtonClicked.clickedButtonQuiz.name; // the button that the user has clicked.
    request.MaxResultsCount = 20;
    PlayFabClientAPI.GetLeaderboard(request, (result) =>
    {
        var resultValue = result.Leaderboard.ElementAt(0).StatValue;
        Debug.Log(resultValue);
        onResult?.Invoke(resltValue);
    }, (error) =>
    {
        Debug.LogError(error.GenerateErrorReport());
    });
}
```

And then instead change your code where you call it to something like

```
GetLeaderboardListAsync(OnLeaderBoardTopAvailable);


private void OnLeaderBoardTopAvailable(int topValue)
{
    // Whatever should happen once you have the index
}
```

---

Btw: Be careful with `Debug.LogError` as it might also prevent the code from executing further. Rather use `Debug.LogWarning` which always continues the code execution.